# curl make error: "missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?)"

Tags: shell, curl, compilation, makefile, debian

I'm trying to build curl 7.38.0 on debian wheezy and keep getting this error after running `./configure`.

```
$ make
Making all in lib
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/abc/curl-7.38.0/lib'
Makefile:2833: *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?).  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/abc/curl-7.38.0/lib'
Makefile:846: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I tried looking at/around lines 2833 or 846 to see if there were excess spaces, but I didn't find any problems. Everything looks fine, so I don't understand why there would be any problems. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered this error a few times before. The error message can be misleading a bit. What I found was that the timestamps of the files in the source directory were messed up for me, so I used `touch` to update them.

```
touch ./*
```

If that doesn't work, try updating all of the files except the `Makefile`.

```
for i in ./*; do [[ $i != ./Makefile ]] && touch $i; done
```

Then run `make`, and the config.status should recheck and proceed with compilation.

Comment: Did this actually work? That's amazing. Also *do not* parse the output of `ls`. Especially in a case like this where `for i in *; do` would work just as well.

Comment: `./*` will get you `./Makefile` as the path.